# What is the benefit of using primarykey and references method in class jooq

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm start the learn jooq. I have mssql server. I create some class the represent table on my server. But I don't understand what is the benefit when I was using **getPrimaryKey** and **getReferences** methods in my table class?

```
class User : TableImpl<Record>("users") {

    companion object {
        val USER = User()
    }

    val id: TableField<Record, Int> = createField("id", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
    val name: TableField<Record, String> = createField("name", SQLDataType.NVARCHAR(50))
    val countryId: TableField<Record, Short> = createField("country_id", SQLDataType.SMALLINT)

    override fun getPrimaryKey(): UniqueKey<Record> = Internal.createUniqueKey(this, id)

    override fun getReferences(): MutableList<ForeignKey<Record, *>> =
        mutableListOf(Internal.createForeignKey(primaryKey, COUNTRY, COUNTRY.id))

}

class Country : TableImpl<Record>("country") {

    companion object {
        val COUNTRY = Country()
    }

    val id: TableField<Record, Short> = createField("id", SQLDataType.SMALLINT)
    val name: TableField<Record, String> = createField("name", SQLDataType.NVARCHAR(100))

    override fun getPrimaryKey(): UniqueKey<Record> =
        Internal.createUniqueKey(this, id)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated meta data is a mix of stuff that's useful...

- to *you*, the API user
- to *jOOQ*, which can reflect on that meta data for a few internal features

For instance, in the case of `getPrimaryKey()`, that method helps with all sorts of CRUD related operations as you can see in the manual:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud

If you're not using the code generator (which would generate all of these methods for you), then there is no need to add them to your classes. You could shorten them to this:

```
class User : TableImpl<Record>("users") {
    companion object {
        val USER = User()
    }
    val id: Field<Int> = createField("id", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
    val name: Field<String> = createField("name", SQLDataType.NVARCHAR(50))
    val countryId: Field<Short> = createField("country_id", SQLDataType.SMALLINT)
}
```

However, using the code generator is strongly recommended for a variety of advanced jOOQ features which you might not get, otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Lukas in addition could I use code generator feature for mssql within free plan?

Comment: @MuratSeyis: mssql support is available with the jOOQ Professional Edition, see https://www.jooq.org/legal/licensing#databases